# Angularjs Service Scope + Bindings

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-service

I am looking to run the following controller but im having trouble with scope.

I have a service that calls two functions that retrieve meta data to populate scope variables.

The issue is that using the service to call back the data interferes with other actions happening in the code. I have a directive on a tag that shows/hides an error on the span element once the rule is validated. This is now not functioning correctly. I run the code without asynchronous functions then everything works correctly.

[My Plunker code is here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Lg5kh9)

and the plunker of the desired behaviour is here

[Plunker working example without dynamic data loading](http://plnkr.co/edit/y7sXQCWh57vEoIIhj5bb?p=info)

```
         <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="control-group" ng-repeat="field in viewModel.Fields">
                <label class="control-label">{{field.label}}</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="{{field.Name}}" ng-model="field.data" validator="viewModel.validator"  ruleSetName="{{field.ruleSet}}"/>
                    <span validation-Message-For="{{field.Name}}"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <button ng-click="save()">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

How do I get all bindings to update so everything is sync and loaded correctly?

```
       angular.module('dataApp', ['servicesModule', 'directivesModule'])
   .controller('dataCtrl', ['$scope', 'ProcessService', 'ValidationRuleFactory',    'Validator',
function($scope, ValidationRuleFactory, Validator, ProcessService) {

  $scope.viewModel = {};
  var FormFields = {};

  // we would get this from the meta api

  ProcessService.getProcessMetaData().then(function(data) {

    alert("here");

    FormFields = {
      Name: "Course",
      Fields: [{
        type: "text",
        Name: "name",
        label: "Name",
        data: "",
        required: true,
        ruleSet: "personFirstNameRules"
      }, {
        type: "text",
        Name: "description",
        label: "Description",
        data: "",
        required: true,
        ruleSet: "personEmailRules"
      }]
    };


    $scope.viewModel.Fields = FormFields;


    ProcessService.getProcessRuleData().then(function(data) {

      var genericErrorMessages = {
        required: 'Required',
        minlength: 'value length must be at least %s characters',
        maxlength: 'value length must be less than %s characters'
      };
      var rules = new ValidationRuleFactory(genericErrorMessages);

      $scope.viewModel.validationRules = {
        personFirstNameRules: [rules.isRequired(), rules.minLength(3)],
        personEmailRules: [rules.isRequired(), rules.minLength(3), rules.maxLength(7)]
      };



      $scope.viewModel.validator = new Validator($scope.viewModel.validationRules);

    });

  });

  var getRuleSetValuesMap = function() {
    return {
      personFirstNameRules: $scope.viewModel.Fields[0].data,
      personEmailRules: $scope.viewModel.Fields[1].data
    };
  };

  $scope.save = function() {
    $scope.viewModel.validator.validateAllRules(getRuleSetValuesMap());
    if ($scope.viewModel.validator.hasErrors()) {
      $scope.viewModel.validator.triggerValidationChanged();
      return;
    } else {
      alert('person saved in!');
    }
  };

}
]);
```

The validation message directive is here

```
(function(angular, $) {

angular.module('directivesModule')
        .directive('validationMessageFor', [function() {
                return {
                    restrict: 'A',
                    scope: {eID: '@val'},
                    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {

                        //var errorElementId = attributes.validationMessageFor;

                        attributes.$observe('validationMessageFor', function(value) {

                            errorElementId = value;

                            //alert("called");

                            if (!errorElementId) {
                                return;
                            }
                            var areCustomErrorsWatched = false;

                            var watchRuleChange = function(validationInfo, rule) {
                                scope.$watch(function() {
                                    return validationInfo.validator.ruleSetHasErrors(validationInfo.ruleSetName, rule.errorCode);
                                }, showErrorInfoIfNeeded);
                            };
                            var watchCustomErrors = function(validationInfo) {
                                if (!areCustomErrorsWatched && validationInfo && validationInfo.validator) {
                                    areCustomErrorsWatched = true;
                                    var validator = validationInfo.validator;
                                    var rules = validator.validationRules[validationInfo.ruleSetName];
                                    for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
                                        watchRuleChange(validationInfo, rules[i]);
                                    }
                                }
                            };

                            // get element for which we are showing error information by id
                            var errorElement = $("#" + errorElementId);
                            var errorElementController = angular.element(errorElement).controller('ngModel');
                            var validatorsController = angular.element(errorElement).controller('validator');

                            var getValidationInfo = function() {
                                return validatorsController && validatorsController.validationInfoIsDefined() ? validatorsController.validationInfo : null;
                            };

                            var validationChanged = false;
                            var subscribeToValidationChanged = function() {
                                if (validatorsController.validationInfoIsDefined()) {
                                    validatorsController.validationInfo.validator.watchValidationChanged(function() {
                                        validationChanged = true;
                                        showErrorInfoIfNeeded();
                                    });

                                    // setup a watch on rule errors if it's not already set
                                    watchCustomErrors(validatorsController.validationInfo);
                                }
                            };

                            var getErrorMessage = function(value) {
                                var validationInfo = getValidationInfo();
                                if (!validationInfo) {
                                    return '';
                                }

                                var errorMessage = "";
                                var errors = validationInfo.validator.errors[validationInfo.ruleSetName];
                                var rules = validationInfo.validator.validationRules[validationInfo.ruleSetName];

                                for (var errorCode in errors) {
                                    if (errors[errorCode]) {
                                        var errorCodeRule = _.findWhere(rules, {errorCode: errorCode});
                                        if (errorCodeRule) {
                                            errorMessage += errorCodeRule.validate(value).errorMessage;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                return errorMessage;
                            };

                            var showErrorInfoIfNeeded = function() {
                                var validationInfo = getValidationInfo();
                                if (!validationInfo) {
                                    return;
                                }

                                var needsAttention = validatorsController.ruleSetHasErrors() && (errorElementController && errorElementController.$dirty || validationChanged);
                                if (needsAttention) {
                                    // compose and show error message
                                    var errorMessage = getErrorMessage(element.val());

                                    // set and show error message
                                    element.text(errorMessage);
                                    element.show();
                                } else {
                                    element.hide();
                                }
                            };

                            subscribeToValidationChanged();
                            if (errorElementController)
                            {
                                scope.$watch(function() {
                                    return errorElementController.$dirty;
                                }, showErrorInfoIfNeeded);
                            }
                            scope.$watch(function() {
                                return validatorsController.validationInfoIsDefined();
                            }, subscribeToValidationChanged());
                        });
                    }
                };
            }]);
    })(angular, $);
```

Comment: Please specify what exactly is the problem.

Comment: @TommyK Yep the problem is unclear... But looks as if the solution could be as simple as moving `$scope.viewModel.validator = new Validator($scope.viewModel.validationRules);` inside the callback function (i.e., after `$scope.viewModel.validationRules = data;`).

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully I have made the issue a little clearer.